# how to fit strip.text.x if the heading string is too long

Tags: r, ggplot2

data frame: x

```
Date          Duration  Test
1/1/2012      10        This is the first that took place on1/1/2012
2/1/2012      3         This test peformed the best result
```

I am having challenges around heading for the strip.text.x fitting the graph. Has anybody have any recommendations how can I address this?

```
ggplot(x, aes(Date, Duration, group=Test, colour=Test)) 
+ geom_line() 
+ geom_smooth(method="lm", se=T, size=1) 
+ facet_wrap(~Test, scale="free") 
+ opts(strip.text.x = theme_text(size=8, colour="navyblue"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use `facet_grid` rather than `facet_wrap`, you can use the functionality of the `labeller` argument to arbitrarily wrap the text. (`facet_wrap` does not ([yet](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/25)) have a `labeller` argument.)

Make `x` reproducible

```
x <-
structure(list(Date = structure(c(-719143, -718778), class = "Date"), 
    Duration = c(10L, 3L), Test = c("This is the first that took place on1/1/2012", 
    "This test peformed the best result")), .Names = c("Date", 
"Duration", "Test"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Helper function to wrap labels (discussed in more detail [on the ggplot2 wiki](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/labeller))

```
library("plyr")
label_wrap_gen <- function(width = 25) {
    function(variable, value) {
      laply(strwrap(as.character(value), width=width, simplify=FALSE), 
            paste, collapse="\n")
    }
}
```

Plotting code. Changed to points since just two values were given so lines and smoothing don't make sense. But those were not the focus of the question anyway.

```
ggplot(x, aes(Date, Duration, group=Test, colour=Test)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~Test, scale="free", labeller=label_wrap_gen(width=10)) + 
  opts(strip.text.x = theme_text(size=8, colour="navyblue"))
```

[image]

EDIT:

Since `facet_grid` won't work for you, you could embed the newlines into the `Test` variable directly and then use `facet_wrap`.

```
x$Test <- laply(strwrap(as.character(x$Test), width=10, simplify=FALSE), 
                paste, collapse="\n")
ggplot(x, aes(Date, Duration, group=Test, colour=Test)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Test, scale="free") + 
  opts(strip.text.x = theme_text(size=8, colour="navyblue"))
```

[image]

I don't understand your other question about headers made in the comment. Perhaps make a new, clearer question out of that.

Comment: since there will be alot more grids, this wont work for me. This is good to know.

Comment: I have another question regarding displaying the headers. If I wanted to put text in top and also right of the y-axix, how would I do that? now I have Date on y-axis and Test on the top of the graph. I really like to put another heading in on the right side of the y-axix in 90 degree angel.

Answer (score 1):

This is now available in `ggplot2::label_wrap_gen`.